# SVG elements rendering in blazor using JSInterop

Tags: c#, svg, blazor

I need to render text elements, line elements, etc in the svg in blazor. So, I have created a jSinterop to perform this operations so that I can call the js methods wherever it is necessary.
My code snippet,

***.razor***

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsInterop

<svg id="parentElement">
    @for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        @RenderTextElements()
    }
    </svg>

@code { 
int count = 10;
public object RenderTextElements()
{
    return (JsInterop.InvokeAsync<object>("elementText", new object[] { }));
}}
```

My js files is

```
window.elementText = function () {
    var svgElement = this.document.getElementById('parentElement');
    var text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');   
    text.setAttribute('fill', 'black');
    text.textContent = 'hello world';
    svgElement.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', text)
}
```

This js method is invoked but text element did not append to DOM.
When I debugging through this method, I can see the element appended to DOM. Later, it is removed. I can't find where it is removed.

Comment: Why do you need JS exactly?  Couldn't you just generate the elements with C#/Blazor?

Comment: yes, I can generate elements in blazor too. Just I need to check the performance of svg rendering with blazor and JS . So that I am checking like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In svg you'll have to set the position for an element:

```
  <script>

    function insertElements() {
      let parent = document.getElementById("parent");

      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "text");
        text.setAttribute("x", 10);
        text.setAttribute("y", 10 + 15 * i);
        text.style.fill = "blue";
        text.textContent = "text " + i;
        parent.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", text);
      }

    }

    function test() {
      insertElements();
    }

  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <button onclick="test()">Test</button>
  <svg id="parent" width="200" height="200">
  </svg>

</body>
```